# Glass arrow heads

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, warfare, weapons, medieval

Can arrows with glass heads be effective and optimally implemented in an early medieval war setting?

I'd imagine it could be cheaper and [faster](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SfMN3BVISmQ) to produce than metal heads, since the shape of the head doesn't matter, and the entire point of a glass head is the fact that it explodes in a cloud of glass upon impact with armor and does well on flesh too.

Therefore it doesn't really matter if it's actual glass, any crystal would work. all it takes is a piece of glass/crystal and a stone 
[image: Photo of a glass/crystal arrowhead]

Comment: This exists.  Ancient peoples made arrowheads and other cutting tools from obsidian, a glass originating from volcanos.  Or did you have another specific composition of glass in mind?

Comment: Yeah, but I was specially referring to its effectiveness as a medieval warfare weapon

Comment: "*cheaper and faster to produce*"... than what?

Comment: You mean glass against armor?

Comment: "*all it takes is a piece of glass/crystal and a stone*" Large crystals are rare.  That's why flint and obsidian (a type of amorphous glass) were so popular.

Comment: Yeah against armor,shields and so on, In history there were many weapons for many uses, I'm more or so interested if glass arrows could have any use, maybe even be efficient or be completely useless

Comment: "*it explodes in a glass cloud upon impact with armor*" You're throwing sand at people.  That's... there's a reason no one ever did that.

Comment: I had the idea from some glass bullets, upon impact they shatter in pieces that  either are lost around or penetrate the target but they also leave behind a big cloud of glass dust

Comment: [Related](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/16938/would-glass-bullets-be-feasible-in-a-hypothetical-world)

Comment: @Ekaen, glass shotgun slugs do work, and leaves glass splinters in the hole, but they are very short range, tumbling and breaking apart in the air. https://youtu.be/7-n4bxxn9gA

Comment: @cobaltduck: Not just ancient people.  Obsidian is still used for surgical scalpels and other specialized cutting tools: http://www.finescience.com/Special-Pages/Products.aspx?ProductId=296&CategoryId=56&lang=en-US

Comment: Australian Aboriginals are very well documented as using salvaged glass in arrows (and other weapons/tools). Not quiet the same, since they were not creating it. But they certainly found it useful.

Comment: https://www.historyonthenet.com/aztec-warriors-weapons-and-armor/  "Basic Aztec armor was quilted cotton of two to three thicknesses. The cotton was soaked in salt brine then hung to dry. The salt crystallized in the material, which gave it the ability to resist obsidian blades and spears." I'd think gambesons, widely worn by most soldiers by themselves or under metal armour would be as good, and if not, would rapidly become so if glass arrows became commonplace

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In principle, glass arrowheads would be highly effective, at least against unarmoured opponents. According to  [this study](https://www.forensicmed.co.uk/wounds/sharp-force-trauma/glass-wounds/), glass shards need to travel in excess of ~15 m/s to deeply penetrate flesh, and the [greenman longbows](http://www.greenmanlongbows.co.uk/SPEED%20TESTING%20Measuring%20the%20arrow%20speed%20of%20bows%20and%20longbows%20using%20a%20chronometer.htm) site rates longbows as propelling arrows with a velocity of around 170 feet per second, or around 52 m/s. Glass arrowheads can - with some practice - be formed in the same manner as flint (or other stone) arrowheads, by [knapping](http://sensiblesurvival.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/making-glass-arrowheads-part-1.html).

The question then is not whether glass arrowheads are effective, but whether glass is economically viable as a material. Glass was manufactured and used in ancient times, as well as in the medieval period, but not typically for arrowheads. There are two possible reasons for this: the skill of knapping stone (or glass) arrowheads was not widely known, or glass was too expensive to be used in such a disposable fashion (at least relative to iron). Information presented [here](https://medievallondon.ace.fordham.edu/collections/show/95) suggests that glass was very expensive to produce.

So in the questioner's world, use of glass (or a crystalline rock that can be similarly knapped) for arrowheads would depend on it being common enough a material that it would be used in preference to e.g. flint or iron.

Comment: to add a little speculation, it may be that the skill of making glass &/or availability of raw materials is restricted within the questioner's world, and so it would only be certain armies that possessed such arrows (or alternatively, the holder of the resources/skills might sell them to the highest bidder, or provide mercenary units equipped with glass arrows.

Comment: Also, iron/steel arrowheads tend to be reusable.

Comment: @vsz sometimes you might not want them to be reusable? Or not metal (see Mistborn trilogy)

Comment: Or if iron's really rare (and therefore expensive), probably don't want to leave it lying around a battlefield - or for that matter, made into armour...

Comment: Would I be wrong to assume that glass arrowheads would shatter against metal armour? (Not that steel arrowheads are all that great at penetrating metal armour either, but still.)

Comment: @Pahlavan I image that they would, but there are accounts of bone arrowheads penetrating steel breast-plates: goo.gl/DdB4ZT

Answer (score 16):

Glass arrow heads are effective and deadly if made well. These are the issues that I would consider for a medieval war scenario...

- It takes much more skill and time to create good knapped arrow heads than it does to make metal ones.
- Metal is more durable than glass so that arrows are more likely to be usable again after they are retrieved
- Metal arrowheads are much more effective at punching through armor. Glass arrow heads would do very poorly and the damage from broken glass would be negligible.

I think that lack of access to metal would be the only plausible reason for armies to use glass heads.

I make wooden self bows for a living and have made arrow heads from glass and obsidian. I'm not an expert on knapping but I know a fair bit from experience and research.

Answer (score 15):

[image: glass arrowheads]

http://raregoldnuggets.com/?p=5497
Sure you could have glass arrowheads.  Obsidian is volcanic glass and makes fine arrowheads.  The Amerinds did this for millennia.

Would someone make arrowheads out of glass if they knew about metal?  Absolutely they would if metal were scarce and valuable and they had plenty of glass and were good at making arrowheads.  Save the metal for your kitchen knives and armor and shoot the cheap glass on your arrows that you may or may not get back.  It makes sense!

Answer (score 9):

One important aspect is the huge durability problem that such weapons would pose, besides being less economically viable than metal arrowheads.

You have to take into consideration that medieval campaigns would often last months, if not years, most of which was spent traveling.
In that respect, the last thing you'd want is brittle arrowheads that will break at the slightest shock and probably even damage each other as the marching bowmen knock the arrows around in their quills while marching.

I can't even start to imagine the logistical nightmare it would be.

For a one-off mission however, like an assassination where you'll get the chance to shoot only one arrow at your target anyway, such an arrow might be interesting against unprotected, high-value target. You could even imagine a hollow glass arrowhead designed like a vial containing a poison, that breaks up and releases the poison upon penetration.

Comment: I really like the idea of an arrow with a hollow core in which you may add substances. Has that been done before?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply ; as far as I know, such a contraption has not been used in arrows (but other projectiles such as bullets or pellets can be hollow in order to contain poison, see the famous Bulgarian umbrella for a example of a real-life assassination tool using poison-filled pellets). Poisoned arrows have been used throughout history, but I only know of instances where the arrows are coated or dipped in a poisonous substance instead of containing the poison itself. This is probably because of the same logistical difficulties I named above.

Answer (score 4):

Is a glass arrowhead possible? [Yes](https://youtu.be/k1xvCH6Lu6c). Using modern glass, an arrow has nearly the same penetration as a modern steel broadhead arrow, when measured using gel powder.

However, in our world, this is not very practical. [Forest glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_glass#Medieval_Europe) was the main type of glass made in Europe in the medieval ages, it was low quality, prone to chipping and cracking. Transporting, storing and marching with glass arrowheads would damage them, making them less useful than metal ones.

The other problem is making them. Glass making was expensive. Cheaper to use bog iron, melt down old metal items, or dig iron out of the ground than go through the trouble to make glass.

If people were low on metals, they would turn to natural glass like obsidian and flint. They're cheaper, easier to make, and not as fragile as the man-made glass of the time.